# Backup type client to server

Tags: linux, backup

I have 250-300 clients with windows os. I would like to make a system backup, type server->client and I don't want to use sharing profile from windows os. Server - linux os, client - windows os. Which software I should use to make backup type server-client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly what you mean by "type server->client" but take a look at [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/). It is a client/server backup software that has a windows client and is very powerful. If you are not using anything fancy on Windows (meaning: you need to copy not much more than files) it will suit you well.

You also can configure it to run a script before the backup and one after, so you can use that to run a specific MS tool to backup the machine, then use Bacula to copy this backup out to tape or disk and then later restore it, but you lose some flexibility on the restore (like the ability to restore individual files).

Comment: Another option may be backuppc http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/ which is very focused to "windows desktops backup to linux backup server"

Comment: backuppc only to linux

Comment: maybe http://gerwick.ucsd.edu/backuppc_manual/backuppc_winxp.html

Answer (score 0):

When backing up windows machines (Vista and newer, I believe), beware of 'junctions' (equivalent of hard links). If your tool doesn't know how to handle them, you will have infinite loops.

I use MS SyncToy. It's a (poor-man's) equivalent of rsync for Windows. I backup to a Linux server, which then backups the network share internally with rdiff-backup, to maintain a very efficient history of backups (because it stores incremental backups).

Comment: Unison is a popular rsync alternative for windows!

Comment: Without junction support, which makes it unusable in my opinion.